# Markers are not showing on the map fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

It's my first time using android studio and i created a navigation bar ,where i'm using a host fragment that contains 3 fragments,one of them is the map fragment,the map is showing but i can't get markers, i don't know if i messed up the map fragment but any help or hint would me much appreciated.
Thank you.

**MapFragment.java**

```
package com.example.sanad;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnMapReadyCallback callback = new OnMapReadyCallback() {

        /**
         * Manipulates the map once available.
         * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
         * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera.
         * In this case, we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
         * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to
         * install it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the
         * user has installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
         */

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-50, 50);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        }

    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);





    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(callback);
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_maps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsFragment"
    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds">
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">


</fragment>
  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure the Latlang is correct?

Comment: it's not sydney's coordinates but i don't get that location,and the camera is not moving,so the hole onMapReady is not getting called.

Comment: Try moving onViewCreated content to onCreateView

Comment: same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

The code seems okay, you could maybe try putting up some debug points to see till what part the code is being called, although I did notice one thing, you could update the `moveCamera` method call to `animateCamera` as it animates the moving and you could maybe know the difference whether it is working or not. Also I updated the correct coordinates too.

```java
 LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(sydney)
        .title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

Comment: Unfortunately,the marker and the animate camera are not working :( .I get the map but the these 2 no. thanks anyway.

Comment: @SyyKee Could you debug as onto what point the code is being called? Maybe the whole `mapReady` callback is not working?